# TypeScript: Specifying values with "%s" when passing an object as parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, decorator

I know that you can decorate strings as such:

```
let name = "Bob";
console.log("Hello, %s.", name) // => Outputs: "Hello, Bob."
```

I want to know if it's possible to access certain values within a passed in object, when you cannot specify the key in the argument. This is during testing in Jest, when iterating over an array of objects:

```
let people = [
  {
   id: 1,
   name: "Bob",
   age: 25
  },
  {
   id: 2,
   name: "Fred",
   age: 19
  }
];
describe.each(people)(
  `When the person is %s`,
  (person) => {
    it(`It should say "Hello, ${person.name}`, () => {...})
  }
```

I'm looking for the logged value in the console to read:
`"When the person is Bob > It should ..."`
... but instead am getting:

```
"When the person is {
   id: 1,
   name: "Bob",
   age: 25
} > It should ...
```

Is there any way to use a decorator like '%s.name' before the object referenced is actually passed in, for the sake of simplifying my test output?

Answer (score 2):

`printf`-style substitutions don't have any intelligence, you'll need to provide the name by itself.

If you don't want to repeat them in your tests, you could do something like this:

```js
let people = [
  // ...
].map(person => ([ person.name, person ])); // <-----------

describe.each(people)(
  `When the person is %s`,
  (name, person) => { //                       <-----------
    it(`It should say "Hello, ${name}`, () => {/* ... */})
  })
```